# Is there a function that, given a column of data.frame returns a list of all column indices that match the condition?

Tags: r

I have a column of numeric data.

I run:

```
which.min(xdata[,5])
```

I get the index where the min value is found.

```
[1] 20
```

Now, how do I extract all the indices of the column that meet the same condition? Perhaps as a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
which(xdata[ , 5] == min(xdata[ , 5]))
```

will work (it returns a vector).

If you want the indices as a list:

```
as.list(which(xdata[ , 5] == min(xdata[ , 5])))
```

Comment: I think the vector solution is what I need. Thank you for sharing that as well.